# F# Async.RunSynchronously with timeout and cancellationToken

Tags: f#, cancellation-token, async-workflow

When calling Async.RunSynchronously with a timeout and a CancellationToken, the timeout value seems to be ignored. I can work around this by calling CancelAfter on the CancellationToken, but ideally I'd like to be able to distinguish between exceptions that occur in the workflow, TimeOutExceptions and OperationCanceledExceptions.

I believe the sample code below demonstrates this.

```
open System
open System.Threading

let work = 
    async {
        let endTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(100.0)
        while DateTime.UtcNow < endTime do
            do! Async.Sleep(10)
            Console.WriteLine "working..."
        raise ( Exception "worked for more than 100 millis" )
    }


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    try
        Async.RunSynchronously(work, 50)
    with
        | e -> Console.WriteLine (e.GetType().Name + ": " + e.Message)

    let cts = new CancellationTokenSource()

    try
        Async.RunSynchronously(work, 50, cts.Token)
    with
        | e -> Console.WriteLine (e.GetType().Name + ": " + e.Message)  


    cts.CancelAfter(80)
    try
        Async.RunSynchronously(work, 50, cts.Token)
    with
        | e -> Console.WriteLine (e.GetType().Name + ": " + e.Message)  

    Console.ReadKey(true) |> ignore

    0
```

The outputs the following, showing that the timeout is only effective in the first case (where no CancelationToken is specified)

```
working...
working...
TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
working...
working...
working...
working...
working...
working...
working...
Exception: worked for more than 100 millis
working...
working...
working...
working...
working...
working...
OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
```

Is this the intended behaviour? Is there any way  get the behaviour I'm after?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour - at least, I do not see any reason why it would be. However, this behaviour is implemented directly in the handling of parameters of `RunSynchronously`. If you look at the [library source code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs#L1333), you can see:

```
static member RunSynchronously (p:Async<'T>,?timeout,?cancellationToken) =
  let timeout,token =
    match cancellationToken with
    | None -> timeout,(!defaultCancellationTokenSource).Token                
    | Some token when not token.CanBeCanceled -> timeout, token                
    | Some token -> None, token
```

In your case (with both timeout and a cancellation token that can be cancelled), the code goes through the last branch and ignores the timeout. I think this is either a bug or it is something that should be mentioned in the documentation.

As a workaround, you can create a separate `CancellationTokenSource` to specify the timeout and link it to the main cancellation source so that the caller provides (using `CreateLinkedTokenSource`). When you get `OperationCancelledException`, you can then detect whether the source was an actual cancellation or a timeout:

```
type Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Async with
  static member RunSynchronouslyEx(a:Async<'T>, timeout:int, cancellationToken) =
    // Create cancellation token that is cancelled after 'timeout'
    let timeoutCts = new CancellationTokenSource()
    timeoutCts.CancelAfter(timeout)

    // Create a combined token that is cancelled either when 
    // 'cancellationToken' is cancelled, or after a timeout
    let combinedCts = 
      CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource
        (cancellationToken, timeoutCts.Token)

    // Run synchronously with the combined token
    try Async.RunSynchronously(a, cancellationToken = combinedCts.Token)
    with :? OperationCanceledException as e ->
      // If the timeout occurred, then we throw timeout exception instead
      if timeoutCts.IsCancellationRequested then
        raise (new System.TimeoutException())
      else reraise()
```

Comment: PS: I reported this to the F# team (if you find other issues, you can use fsbugs _at_ microsoft _dot_ com)

Comment: I'm not sure when this was added, but documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370262.aspx says that `If you provide a cancelable cancellation token, the timeout is ignored`.

Comment: @TomasPetricek by any chance you have a link to that old report? btw today I asked a similar question to this one but without the synchronous part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978550/async-start-with-timeout-and-cancellationtoken