# Async.Start with timeout and cancellationToken?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, timeout, cancellation, cancellation-token

I have an `Async<'T>` computation that I want to run, and obtain the result `'T`.

I only have two requirements:

1. After certain `timeout:TimeSpan` has passed, I want the computation/IO to be aborted.
2. I want to run it with a `cancellationToken` just in case I want to abort it before `timeout` has passed.

According to my requirement (1) above, you might think that `Async.StartChild` is a good candidate because it accepts a timeout parameter, however, it doesn't accept a cancellationToken parameter!

It seems that the other `Async.` methods in the API that accept a cancellationToken either don't return anything (so I cannot await for the result), or only work for `Async<unit>`, or don't allow me a way to combine it with Async.StartChild to achieve both of my requirements.

Also, I need to implement this inside an `async{}` block, which means that using `Async.RunSynchronously` inside it (just in case you suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14439713/544947)) would look either problematic or ugly.

Am I overlooking anything?

Thanks!

Comment: One option is to use a CancellationTokenSource with a timeout and use its CreateLinkedTokenSource method to combine it with your other cancel token.

Comment: thanks I'll try this, but I suppose that the disadvantage of this is the abortion would happen with an OperationCanceledException instead of a TimeOutException :-(

Comment: I think you shouldn't try to cancel the inner async that you would start with Async.StartChild but cancel the outer async, which in turn cancels the inner async. Or if you would cancel only the inner async then would the outer async await the result from the inner indefinitely?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by [hvester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5151798/hvester), you do not need to pass a CancellationToken when starting the Child computation. It will be shared by the Parent and would cancel both, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15284325).

```
let work dueTime = async{
    do! Async.Sleep dueTime
    printfn "Done" }
let workWithTimeOut timeForWork timeOut = async{
    let! comp = Async.StartChild(work timeForWork, timeOut)
    return! comp }

workWithTimeOut 200 400 |> Async.Start // prints "Done"
workWithTimeOut 400 200 |> Async.Start // throws System.TimeoutException

let cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()   
Async.Start(workWithTimeOut 400 200, cts.Token)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 100
cts.Cancel() // throws System.OperationCanceledException
```